# How to get the ID value from selected particular field using text box autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is the code I have used to get auto complete

In HTML View

```
<script>
    $(function () {
                $("#autoComp").autocomplete({
                    source: '@Url.Action("GetAutoComp")',
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        $("#autoComp").val(i.item.val);
                    },
                    minLength: 1
        });
    });

</script>
```

In Action GETAUTOCOMP I have Called a webservice

```
  public JsonResult GetAutoComp(string term)
        {
            ProcorreService.ProcorreWebService service = new ProcorreService.ProcorreWebService();
            string[] rst = service.Autocomplete(term);

           return Json(rst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
```

In a sperate server Web Service I have written the folllowing code to retrive the data from database

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> Autocomplete(string autoName)
{
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TESTDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

String query = @"Select CountryName,ID from Country where CountryName LIKE ''+@SearchFname+'%'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchFname", autoName);

List<string> list = new List<string>();

con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
list.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", dr["COYNTRYNAME"], dr["ID"]));
}

return list;
}
```

This code works fine and it retrieves the data to the HTML view but when select the list it returns the country name but I need to get the ID of the country to be returned

So to get the ID of the country I have tried the Following Ways

1. I Have tried to Convert the List to Json as wanted by the autocomplete.
2. And also I have tried to retrieve the Data from the jquery using ajax inside the jquery itself.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>',
                   data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   success: function (data) {
                       response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                           return {
                               label: item.split('-')[0],
                               val: item.split('-')[1]
                           }
                       }))
                   },
                   error: function (response) {
                       alert(response.responseText);
                   },
                   failure: function (response) {
                       alert(response.responseText);
                   }
               });
           },
           select: function (e, i) {
               $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
           },
           minLength: 1
       });
   });
   ```

In second condition it shows a error such as **no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access** to solve this error I have tried to add the following headers in the server but It does not solve the issue

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!-- Enable Cross Domain AJAX calls -->
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
```

I have tried to get Id by many methods but couldn't able to get any help or link to how to get the ID might be helpfull thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

replace val with value while processing data returned from ajax call

```
return {
   label: item.split('-')[0],
   value: item.split('-')[1]
}
```

...and modify select as below

```
select: function (e, i) {
    $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.value);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '35' in {"label[0]":"vijay","value[0]":"11"}

Comment: I have get console error ["vijay-11"]
jquery.min.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedjquery.min.js:34 b.extend.mapCreateProject:23 $.ajax.successjquery.min.js:142 c.extend.handleSuccessjquery.min.js:141 c.extend.ajax.w.onreadystatechange